# Why does $|e^{2iz}|\leq |e^{2i(x+iy)}|\leq |e^{2ix}||e^{-2y}|\leq 1$ for $z$ in the upper half plane?

Tags: complex-analysis

Why does $|e^{2iz}|\leq |e^{2i(x+iy)}|\leq |e^{2ix}||e^{-2y}|\leq 1$ for $z$ in the upper half plane?

Is it just because it is a complex number with modulus $1$ and all you are doing by changing $z$ is just rotating it around but not actually changing it's modulus?

If that is the case then why do the steps need to be written out as above surely $|e^{2iz}|=1$ would make more sense to write?

Any assistance?

Context: Using a semicircle contour to evaluate a real integral using complex integral.

[http://imgur.com/OVtil3l](https://imgur.com/OVtil3l)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: http://imgur.com/OVtil3l Here is where it comes from if that helps at all?

Comment: My mistake.  $e^{2iz}$ doesn't have modulus $1$ (or even constant modulus), as $|e^{2iz}|= |e^{2i(x+iy)}|=|e^{2ix}||e^{-2y}|=|e^{-2y}|$, so the modulus depends solely on $y$, and is only $1$ if $y=0$.  We can't write $|e^{2iz}|=1$ because this isn't true in general.  To see this more specifically, let $z=5i$, which is in the upper half plane.  Then, we have that $|e^{2i(5i)}|=|e^{-10}|\neq 1$.

Comment: In the upper half-plan, $y\geq 0$, hence $e^{-2y} \leq 1$.

Comment: Got it thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written it slightly differently than the image. You have that

$$|e^{2iz}| = |e^{2ix}||e^{-2y}| = 1\cdot |e^{-2y}| = e^{-2y}. $$

So the magnitude depends on $y$, i.e. the imaginary part of $z$.

Futhermore, we have that $e^{-2y}\leq 1$ for all $y\geq 0$, because $e^{-2y}$ is strictly decreasing as $y$ increases, and $e^{-2\cdot 0} = 1$.

Comment: Oh I think I see because we have it in the form $|Re^{i\theta}|$ with $R=|e^{-2y}|$ and since we are in the upper half plane then $y>0$ so $|e^{-2y}|\leq 1 $?